# Divide a js object into multiple object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "answer": [
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
                "mark": 3.6470588235294117
            },
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
                "mark": 3.3157894736842106
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5d68ba1a-1c0a-4bd0-b5a5-d7a33342ad86",
        "answer": [
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
                "mark": 3.3333333333333335
            },
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
                "mark": 2.5384615384615383
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to divide each object into multiple based in the answer property. So in return i want the following object:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "answer": {
            "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
            "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
            "mark": 3.6470588235294117
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "answer": {
            "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
            "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
            "mark": 3.3157894736842106
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5d68ba1a-1c0a-4bd0-b5a5-d7a33342ad86",
        "answer": {
            "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
            "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
            "mark": 3.3333333333333335
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5d68ba1a-1c0a-4bd0-b5a5-d7a33342ad86",
        "answer": {
            "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
            "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
            "mark": 2.5384615384615383
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add the code you have used and ask a specific question about your issue with the code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.concat`

```js
const input = [
    {
        "id": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "answer": [
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
                "mark": 3.6470588235294117
            },
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
                "mark": 3.3157894736842106
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5d68ba1a-1c0a-4bd0-b5a5-d7a33342ad86",
        "answer": [
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
                "mark": 3.3333333333333335
            },
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
                "mark": 2.5384615384615383
            }
        ]
    }
];


const output = input.reduce((out, {id, answer}) => out.concat(answer.map(a => ({ id, answer: a}))), []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this one with a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let arr = [{ id: "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", answer: [{ region: "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5", country: "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7", mark: 3.6470588235294117 }, { region: "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5", country: "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9", mark: 3.3157894736842106 }] }, { id: "5d68ba1a-1c0a-4bd0-b5a5-d7a33342ad86", answer: [{ region: "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5", country: "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7", mark: 3.3333333333333335 }, { region: "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5", country: "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9", mark: 2.5384615384615383 }] }];

let newArr = arr.flatMap(obj => {
  return obj.answer.map(answer => {
    return {
      id: obj.id,
      answer: answer
    }
  })
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qtxmrj2w/2/

Comment: It is for fans of rxJs. Nice usage )

Comment: Inside, `obj.answer.map` is sufficient. `flatMap` is not needed (Also, please read: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992))

Comment: @adiga Thanks I was always wondering how but didn't take the time to look it up. Will make sure to use that going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
let result = [];
let id;
let answer;
let arr = [<your array ...>];

for({id, answer} of arr) {
    for(let entry of answer) {
        result.push({id: id, answer: entry})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = [
    {
        "id": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "answer": [
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
                "mark": 3.6470588235294117
            },
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
                "mark": 3.3157894736842106
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5d68ba1a-1c0a-4bd0-b5a5-d7a33342ad86",
        "answer": [
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a892904c800e7fe4e0b7",
                "mark": 3.3333333333333335
            },
            {
                "region": "5d41a87d904c800e7fe4e0b5",
                "country": "5d41a8ab904c800e7fe4e0b9",
                "mark": 2.5384615384615383
            }
        ]
    }
]

const result = input.reduce((accumulatedArr, currentElement) => {
  const { answer } = currentElement;
  const currentElementInstances = answer.map((answerInstance) => {
    return {
      ...currentElement,
      'answer': answerInstance
    }
  })

  return [...accumulatedArr, ...currentElementInstances]
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be like:

```
let arr = [];
input.forEach(obj => {
  obj.answer.forEach(value => {
    let obj2 = {};
    obj2.id = obj.id;
    obj2.answer = value;
    arr.push(obj2);
    })
})

console.log(arr);
```